# Where to get statistics about papers mentioning specific keywords?

Tags: publications, research-process, data, statistics, databases

I am currently gathering info about the state of the art of some topic.
What I want to do is to get statistics about how often the topic was mentioned in papers in combination with other keywords in the last couple of years.

Something like this:

```
Year   "topic keyword1"   "topic keyword2"   "topic keyword3"
2017    81                420                121
2016    76                391                101
2015    64                358                92
...     ...               ...                ...
```

Is there a place where i can get this kind of information in an "easy to process" format?
(I used ScienceDirect and other databases and copied the information by hand so far but that is not a good solution imho.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In clinical research you could use pubmed.gov.

Comment: @Joe_74 Thanks for the comment. The "Results by year" with "Download CSV" there would be exactly what I´m looking for. But my field is computer science / machine learning.

Comment: _My field is computer science_ -- Then you should be able to replace most of that manual labor with code. No?

Comment: When I did this, I had to download all the papers in my dataset and use grep.

Comment: @JeffE Of course i could write a script that automates the search request on a website and parses the reply but maybe there is already a solution/software/website or at least an API that covers several databases for that.

Answer (score 1):

What about google scholar? You won't get such a nice formated output, but you will get number of hits for each keyword or combination of keywords

Comment: If I understand correctly this would be the same kind of thing i did with the databases: Actually searching the combinations i need and copy them per year by hand? Or does google scholar offer another solution to this?

Comment: I don't think that there is an easier way to do it unless you find a database that contains this information, offers an API and you write a program to extract the information via the API.

Comment: you can also ask you librarian/data management person (not sure about the correct term here), to help you with that, it's their job, and I heard they are good at it. Although you might have to pay